# Integration tests broken after migrating to ASP.NET Core RC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, integration-testing

In my integration tests, I use a `TestServer` class to work towards a test server instance for my integration tests. In RC1, I instanciated it using the following code:

```
var server = new TestServer(TestServer.CreateBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
```

On RC2, TestServer.CreateBuilder() was removed. Therefore, I tried to create a new TestServer using the following code:

```
var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
```

The problem I'm facing is that after RC2, the runtime is unable to resolve dependencies for DI, so that it throws exceptions on the Configure method for the Startup class. The system does however start up if I start the actual server (not the test project). The exception thrown is as following:

```
  System.Exception : Could not resolve a service of type 'ShikashiBot.IShikashiBotManager' for the parameter 'botManager' of method 'Configure' on type 'ShikashiBot.Startup'.
```

I'm currently using the following package for the test host: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.0.0-rc2-final`

Comment: It sounds like you're missing some types from the DI container. But the type is not coming from ASP.NET. Probably it's one of your types `ShikashiBot.IShikashiBotManager`

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci as I said in my original post, if that was the case, my application would not have started if I started it as normal. There was also no changes to the items that were added to the DI container during the migration.

Comment: Are you sure there's not something in `Program.cs` that's not included in `Startup`?

Comment: If you could share more code or a simple repo that would help a lot

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci thanks, the project is on an open repo at https://bitbucket.org/shikashibot/shikashibot you can find both Program.cs and Startup.cs for the main project under the "ShikashiBot" project, and the integration tests under "ShikashiBot.IntegrationTests"

Comment: I tried to build your solution @Martin, but I get build errors about resolving packages `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory`, `AutoFixture.Xunit2`, `AutoFixture.AutoMoq` and `dotnet-test-xunit`. Does it build for you properly?

Comment: @MarkVincze oops, my bad, add the nuget resource https://www.myget.org/F/xunit/api/v3/index.json and it should compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed some changes to get your repo to work:

1. I had to rename `appsettings.sample.json` to `appsettings.json`, I guess this is just because it's not in source control.
2. I had to add `"buildOptions": { "copyToOutput": [ "appsettings.json" ] }` to the `project.json` of the IntegrationTests project.
3. Had to change the log level `Verbose` to `Debug` in your `appsettings.json`.

But after this the integration test `EndPointsRequiresAuthorization` goes through the dependency injection, and for me it fails with an exception in `ShikashiBotManager`, I guess because I don't have the Postgre DB set up.
For you it already fails before this, because it cannot resolve the `IShikashiBotManager` interface, right?

Can you try to do a complete purge of your local repository with `git clean -xfd` (**NOTE**: your not commited local changes will be deleted), rebuild and try again?

Comment: It seems like the missing configuration (step 2) was the main cause for my issue. I still find it odd though that a missing configuration file causes the IShikashiBotManaged to be unresolved. Cheers!

Comment: The resolution of .net core types appears to be a very strange process indeed. The mysteries of the internal workings of project.json may remain obscure for some time.